# Remove the white background in the Panel

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

How do i get rid of the White background. Here's the image, and i need to get rid of the white background, finally it should show the default `blue colour` of the `panel`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `plain: true`, in the panel's config.

Comment: Nothing hapense, still it is the same.

Answer (score 9):

What works for me is simply:

```
bodyStyle : 'background:none', // Removes the default white background
```

Answer (score 0):

add config

```
 bodyCls:'your-css'
```

or

```
`cls:'your-css'`
```

add css style in default.html or your specific style sheet.

```
.your-css 
{
  background-color:#4169E1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Where should i add `baseCls:'your-css'` ? in app.js ?

Comment: sorry its bodyCls in your panel config